# onClick with string in parameter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-dialog

Hey i'm in the middle of making an event calendar. Each event in the calendar is respresented by a button and when i click it i want to pass some variables with it. Right now it will only let me pass the $id and for some reason neither of my two string variables ($description and $title)

Code for the onClick button and the foreach loop where i get the information:

```
 $event_day = $day_num . '.' . $month . '.' . $year;
foreach ($eventArray as $currentEvent) {
    $result = $string->convert_timestamp_to_string($currentEvent['start_date']);
    if ($result === $event_day) {
        $id = $currentEvent['id'];
        $title = $currentEvent['title'];
        $description = $currentEvent['description'];
        $pageContent .= '<input type="button" class="event" onClick="showDialog('.$id. $description. $title.')" value="' . $title . '"/>';

    }
}
```

Here is the function that's supposed to create the dialog based on the variables passed

```
var showDialog = function(id, description, title) {
$("#dialog-modal").dialog({title:title});
```

};

I have tried seperating the variables with commas with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: they should be comma separated, and watch the quotes

Comment: try `.id.','.$description.','.$title.`

Comment: Also if the the values are strings you need to have quotes around them so it should be `.\'$id\'.','.\'$description\'.','.\'$title\'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably just weren't separating with commas correctly. Try this:

```
onclick="showDialog(\''.$id.'\',\''.$description.'\',\''.$title.'\')"
```

You may also run into issues if your values contain single quotes.

Another option that might work better is putting each value in a `data-` attribute, binding the events with jQuery, and grabbing the values from the `data-` attributes in the handler.

Comment: Do not write attribute names in *camelCase* please.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried quoting the string variables:

```
$pageContent .= '<input type="button" class="event" onClick="showDialog(\''.$id. '\',\''.$description. '\',\''.$title.'\')" value="' . $title . '"/>';
```

Comment: I forgat, also you must separate by a comma the parameters

Answer (score 0):

You certainly need to use commas. If you're using commas, and its still not working, I would

```
echo $description;
echo $title;
```

Just to make sure they are populated and you're not passing empty variables.